# How do I merge two divs with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If my HTML looks like this:

```
 <div class="awesome">
      <p>Some words of wisdom</p>
 </div>
 <div class="awesome">
      <select name="awesome-options">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

How can I make it look like this with jquery:

```
 <div class="awesome">
      <p>Some words of wisdom</p>
      <select name="awesome-options">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

I'm still learning jquery and I know how to replace tags or remove them, I just can't figure out how to only remove part of them.

Comment: No it doesn't. Read it again. The other question *is* trying to combine two divs that have the same class as each other, where the children a have different class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combine all HTML into one variable, delete all DIVs but the first one(Unless you want a new tag!, then add combined HTML into the DIV (Or create a new one with the combined HTML).

```
var combinedHTML = "";
$(".awesome").each(function () {
    combinedHTML += $(this).html();
});

$(".awesome").not(':first').remove();
$(".awesome").html(combinedHTML);
```